# What is the pseudocode for strcpy?

Tags: pseudocode

```
gets(name);
    strcpy(describe1, "Hello ! :D\n");
    strcpy(describe2, "Welcome to travel fun\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t- Travelling made special -\n");
```

Comment: this seems to be off topic for the tex site.

Comment: Hi, welcome to TeX.SX! This question seems offtopic, since `strcpy` refers to C, not TeX and friends. You might have better luck in StackOverflow.